# Show up a question to the interesting tab

Tags: discussion

How to show up an old question in the interesting tab without using a bounty? Should I just wait until someone answer?

Comment: Why do you what to show the question in the interesting tab?

Comment: new questions are showing in this tab so they can be viewed by users

Comment: You can edit it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to manually show a question in the interesting tab. If you want to draw attention to an old question, you should add a bounty on that question. However if you improve the question by editing it, it will be bumped in [the active tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active) and it will get some attention. But don't just edit to bump the question.